# Printing an actual suit on a LEGO figure

Tags: customization

I love LEGO bricks, and I'm always looking for more unique figs. I go on eBay all the time, and one person named [onlinesailin](http://www.ebay.com/usr/onlinesailin) makes AMAZINGLY detailed and cool guys. I want to know how to actually PRINT on costumes like the Joker's suit, or Batman's armored suit from Arkham Knight. What do I need? A certain printer or what? Thanks for answering guys!